# python return list from linux command output

Tags: python, linux, list, tuples, popen

I am new to python and I'm learning rapidly, but this is beyond my current level of understanding. I'm trying to to pull the output from the linux command apcaccess into a list in python.

apcaccess is a linux command to get the status of an APC UPS. The output is this:

```
$ apcaccess
APC      : 001,035,0933
DATE     : 2014-11-12 13:38:27 -0500  
HOSTNAME : doormon
VERSION  : 3.14.10 (13 September 2011) debian
UPSNAME  : UPS
CABLE    : USB Cable
DRIVER   : USB UPS Driver
UPSMODE  : Stand Alone
STARTTIME: 2014-11-12 12:28:00 -0500  
MODEL    : Back-UPS ES 550G 
STATUS   : ONLINE 
LINEV    : 118.0 Volts
LOADPCT  :  15.0 Percent Load Capacity
BCHARGE  : 100.0 Percent
TIMELEFT :  46.0 Minutes
MBATTCHG : 5 Percent
MINTIMEL : 3 Minutes
MAXTIME  : 0 Seconds
SENSE    : Medium
LOTRANS  : 092.0 Volts
HITRANS  : 139.0 Volts
ALARMDEL : 30 seconds
BATTV    : 13.6 Volts
LASTXFER : No transfers since turnon
NUMXFERS : 2
XONBATT  : 2014-11-12 12:33:35 -0500  
TONBATT  : 0 seconds
CUMONBATT: 53 seconds
XOFFBATT : 2014-11-12 12:33:43 -0500  
STATFLAG : 0x07000008 Status Flag
SERIALNO : 4B1335P17084  
BATTDATE : 2013-08-28
NOMINV   : 120 Volts
NOMBATTV :  12.0 Volts
FIRMWARE : 904.W1 .D USB FW:W1
END APC  : 2014-11-12 13:38:53 -0500
```

I've tried different iterations of `Popen` such as:

```
def check_apc_ups():
  output = subprocess.Popen("apcaccess", stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  x1, x2, x3, x4, x5 = output
```

I would like to be able to pull each line into a list or tuple containing all 32 and then only display/print what I need, such as `TIMELEFT` and `BCHARGE`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: sounds like you want str.split('\n')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are already answers how to get the output of the command into python.

It is not clear what you are going to do with the output. Maybe, a dictionary (dict) is better than a list for you:

```
# stolen from Hackaholic's answer
import subprocess
child = subprocess.Popen('apcaccess',stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
msg,err = child.communicate()

# now create the dict:
myDict={}
#for i in msg.split("\n"):  # loop over lines
for i in msg.splitlines():  # EDIT: See comments  
    splitted=i.split(":")  # list like ["HOSTNAME ", " doormon"]
    # remove leading & trailing spaces, add to dict
    myDict[splitted[0].strip()]=splitted[1].strip() 


#Now, you can easily access the items:
print myDict["SERIALNO"]
print myDict["STATUS"]
print myDict["BATTV"]

for k in myDict.keys():
    print k +" = "+ myDict[k]
```

Comment: I like the thought of using Dict but I get an 'IndexError: list index out of range' when I use the above code.

Comment: Hmm, I don't have your apaccess here. However, if msg is a string with newline characters '\n`, it should work. (tested here). May be

Comment: sorry, I sent the comment by accident. What I wanted to say: I quess your end-of-line identifier is different. linux uses `\n`, windows `\r\n` and Mac `\r`. you can check it by `print reprr(msg)`. To get rid of it, `msg.splitlines()` instead of `msg.split("\n")` should help.

Answer (score 1):

```
from subprocess import check_output
out = check_output(["apcaccess"])

spl = [ele.split(":",1)for ele in out.splitlines()]
d = {k.rstrip():v.lstrip() for k,v in spl}

print(d['BCHARGE'])
print(d["TIMELEFT"])
100.0 Percent
46.0 Minutes


from subprocess import check_output
def get_apa():
    out = check_output(["apcaccess"])
    spl = [ele.split(":", 1) for ele in out.splitlines()]
    d = {k.rstrip(): v.lstrip() for k, v in spl}
    return d

output = get_apa()
print (output['BCHARGE'])
100.0 Percent
```

To print all key/values pairings:

```
for k,v in get_apa().items():
    print("{} = {}".format(k,v))
```

Comment: How would I return this information from a function?

Comment: can you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: Sorry. I am new to python so my example may not make sense, but here goes. I want to use this code in a function that can be called every X minutes:

    def check_apc_ups():
        out = check_output(["apcaccess"])

        spl = [ele.split(":",1)for ele in out.splitlines()]
        d = {k.rstrip():v.lstrip() for k,v in spl}

        return (d['BCHARGE'])
        return (d["TIMELEFT"])

Comment: so you want to return the dict in a function? I added it it as as a function, you can get any data by using the key

Comment: If it can be a dict I'm good with that. I'm just fuzzy on how to pull such a large list from a function properly and efficiently.

Comment: i have added the function already, it returns the dict, you just need to access by key as in my example

Comment: Thanks for the updated code. I will go over it, and then see if I can understand and implement it. :-)

Comment: no worries, it is pretty straightforward. the keys are all the words on the left hand side of the output from apcaccess, to get the values you just use that key on the dict.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is `subprocess` module

```
import subprocess
child = subprocess.Popen('apcaccess',stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
msg,err = child.communicate()
print(msg.split())
```